# Network locations with Network Manager (Mint 19.2 + Cinnamon)

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint

I switched from Macbook to Thinkpad with Linux.

We have two environments/locations in the company: the office (10.0.x.x) and  the datacenter (10.1.x.x). We also have about 10 VLANs in every environment. It's currently a pain to change all VLANs every time I go into data center. Also I couldn't find any settings for it.

Is it possible to setup locations in Linux like in MacOS and just switch them?

Answer (score 1):

I took a deeper look and I think I just figured it out.

1. In *Network Settings* select the *Wired* connection and rename it to e.g. Office and also remove the tick *Connect automatically*
2. Then add a new profile, give it a name and also remove the tick. Use the same *MAC address* as in first profile (the one of your physical network interface)
3. Now open *Network connections*, add new VLANs and assign them to appropriate interfaces by selecting *Parent interface*. Set VLAN ID and other network settings if needed.
4. Depending on your location, go into *Network Settings* and just click on the interface to activate it.

Looks like this (just re-created VLANs, so ignore "Last Used" column):

[image: Network connections]